# Export MySQL data to separate txt files

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database dump of about 250,000 records. I am very new to MySQL, and I need each of these records exported into their own .txt file. Is there any way to do this using MySQL? If not, could I do this with Java code?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean you need to have 250,000 distinct .txt files for this?

Comment: and a warning: 250k files is a large number of files. might not fit in a single directory depending on your filesystem and its settings (and if it does, not fun listing that thing).

Comment: yes, I need each record in a distinct .txt file. My filesystem and settings will handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can output a select statement to a file but only one file at a time

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/outputfile.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

I would recommend outputting from MySQL into a single file and then breaking that file up using `split` in Linux (hopefully that's your OS)

```
split -l 1 -a 20 outputfile.csv
```

If it says output file suffixes exhausted, you will have to increase the -a value to something higher